# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 alonside Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I have a laptop with windows 10 and I want to install both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 alonside with windows. How do I do that? Does the installing order of 18.04 and 20.04 matters?

Comment: The order doesn't matter (with regards Ubuntu releases or in fact windows and Ubuntu though you may need extra steps to correct booting with windows & Ubuntu), you can just use a *something else* install, or *install alongside* (auto-resize) and install multiple systems alongside each other (on separate disks, or the same physical disk; it's entirely up to you... I've had 7 installed on a single box across 3 drives; a QA *test* system)